# websocket организация отправки и получения сообщений

Tags: php, javascript, websocket

Ставлю websocket на сервер, без nodejs.

В качестве сервера использую вот это решение: 
https://github.com/Doncode/simple_php_websocket_server

Запускаю сервер из браузера.

на клиенте:

```
var socket = new WebSocket("ws://мой адрес:9000/ws");

socket.onopen = function() {
    alert("Соединение установлено.");
};

socket.onclose = function(event) {
  if (event.wasClean) {
    alert('Соединение закрыто чисто');
  } else {
    alert('Обрыв соединения'); 
  }
  alert('Код: ' + event.code + ' причина: ' + event.reason);
};

socket.onmessage = function(event) {
  alert("Получены данные " + event.data);
};

socket.onerror = function(error) {
  alert("Ошибка " + error.message);
};


setInterval(function() {
    socket.send('msg1');
}, 5000);
```

Соединение устанавливается, ошибок нет.

Но как заставить сервер ответить? Он молчит как рыба...

В библиотеке есть функция

```
function websocket_onmessage($keyINsock, $str){
echo "\r\n";
echo "WEBSOCKET_ONMESSAGE[$keyINsock] $str \r\n";
echo "\r\n";
websock_send($keyINsock, $str); //эхо
```

}

Как я понимаю она должна срабатывать после каждого полученного сообщения, но этого не происходит. Как быть? Проблема с сервером?

Comment: странный у вас порт `9000` он вроде по умолчанию на `888` порт запускаеться судя по докам.

Comment: Это я уже экспериментировал. Конечно же, я поменял порт и на сервере.

Comment: а что нибудь выводите в порт?

Comment: А как посмотреть? Я на разных портах попробовал, не помогает. 
888, 9000, 888, 9001, 9999....

Comment: Ну так вы должны што то вывести туда к примеру сделать 'fwrite' в фаил сокета как минимум

Comment: То есть сервер в принципе не должен отвечать на мои сообщения? Зачем тогда в файле use.php есть echo...? Во всех примерах что видел, все просто запускают это и всё работает.

Comment: А как сервер поймёт, что ему отвечать на ваши сообщения? Вы должны ему объяснить

Comment: Там в библиотеке уже указаны функции. Они должны отвечать,но ответа нет..

Answer (score 1):

> Ставлю websocket на сервер, без nodejs.
>   Не понял смысла в этой фразе, ты ставишь PHP реализацию по ссылке ниже - естественно оно без nodejs!
>
> В качестве сервера использую вот это решение: https://github.com/Doncode/simple_php_websocket_server

У проекта simple_php_websocket_server - 14 stars не рекомендую его использовать

Рекомендую взять https://github.com/ratchetphp/Ratchet он строиться на базе асинхронного фреймворка ReactPHP https://github.com/reactphp/react
Не забудь поставить любую реализацию EventLoop что бы не использовать stream

После того как преступишь к тестированию
Открой средства разработчика в браузере - Network -> WS -> Click on your connection -> и увидишь все frame от сервера

Удачной разработки!

Comment: Спасибо. Но мне не нужны такие монстры. Мне нужна простенькая реализация сервера, который бы хоть как-то отвечал на сообщения. Дальше бы я понял в чём дело и дописал бы нужные мне модули. А пока я не могу понять что-то не так на сервере или дело именно в неправильно работающем фреймворке.